# Как лучше организовать обмен данными по сокетам между пользователями?

Tags: node.js, разработка-игр, socket.io

Я не буду описывать реальную ситуацию, т.к. она довольно непроста, попробую рассказать суть, которой хочется добиться и собственно услышать ваши мнения по этому вопросу.

Итак, представьте ситуацию: есть игра, в которой игроки подключаются к комнате и ждут ее начала. Когда игра начинается (неважно, как она начинается, просто началась), каждый игрок об этом узнает посредством broadcast-а. Тут все хорошо. Далее у каждого игрока запускается таймер с интервалом в 1 секунду (грубо говоря продолжительность текущей игры). Каждую секунду каждый игрок генерирует число (в нашем общем случае пусть это будет какое-то random значение) и ему необходимо это число разослать всем участникам этой комнаты, а им в свою очередь надо получить это число в эту же секунду. Серверная часть написана на Node.js и Socket.io.

Например:

1. есть игрок1 и игрок2
2. началась игра
3. 1ая секунда игры: игрок1 отправил
   на сервер число 15, а игрок 2 -
   число 18
4. в эту же 1ую секунду игрок1
   должен увидеть, что игрок2 отправил
   число 18, а игрок2 должен увидеть,
   что игрок1 отправил число 15

Проблема в том, что я не уверен, как правильно это реализовать, т.к. не знаю, успеют ли данные доходить до игроков за эту 1ую секунду, ведь им надо отправить свое число, а всем остальным получить это число за ту же секунду. Я вижу 2 варианта:

- Игрок1 отправляет свое число на
  сервер. Складываем это число в
  массив, примерно такой:
  usersPoints[userId][second] = points.
  В эту же секунду игрок2 запрашивает
  данные из массива и уже смотрит,
  сколько очков у игрока1. Проблема: я
  не уверен, что данные от игрок1
  успеют положиться в массива раньше,
  чем игрок2 их запросит.
- Игрок1 отправляет свое число на
  сервер. Сервер броадкастит в комнату
  это число. Проблема: я не уверен, что
  число от игрока1 дойдет до сервера
  именно в ту секунду, когда оно нужно
  игроку2. Ну, возьмем к примеру
  медленный интернет. Получается, что
  по таймеру у игрока1 сработает
  событие "отправить число на сервер".
  Игрок2 в эту же секунду будет ждать
  число от игрок1, но т.к. у игрок1
  медленный интернет, а таймер игрока2
  его ждать не будет, то игрок2 может
  просто не дождаться этого числа.

Я тестировал 1ый вариант и результат был ожидаемый (мной), число то доходило (до всех остальных), то нет. Пробовал отправлять очки не каждую секунду, а каждые 990мс, а запрашивать каждую секунду, но тогда со временем (уже минуты через 2) они уже становятся не совсем актуальными.

Если вам не совсем понятно, зачем игрокам отправлять и получать числа, то давайте попробую объяснить в целом. Когда игра стартует каждую секунду каждый игрок своими действиями генерирует количество очков. Остальные игроки должны видеть его очки в эту секунду (а он видеть очки других игроков), чтобы сравнивать их со своими.

Я в отчаянии. Вроде и проблема совсем обычная, обмен актуальными данными в текущую секунду, а какой выбрать подход - не знаю. Отсюда и вопрос: каким наилучшим образом организовать обмен актуальными данными между игроками в течение одной секунды?

Comment: ну и ещё, тут против вас работает [CAP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_CAP)

Comment: @eicto, спасибо, дельный совет

Comment: @likerRr, когда Вы говорите одновременно о бродкасте и интернете, то что именно Вы имеете в виду?

Обычно с broadcast (в традиционном понимании этого термина) связано

- LAN (по сути отправителю (сетевому  устройству) известны MAC получателей)

- UDP (нет соединения)

--

А в принципе, @eicto указал Вам совершенно правильный ход мыслей

    ... весь вопрос не в том как передать, а что делать, если данные не пришли ...

Продумайте, что должно происходить в игре, если несколько игроков "отвалились".

Comment: @avp, я имел ввиду broadcast, в смысле вещания сообщений в комнаты. В socket.io этот термин означает, что сообщения шлются всем в комнате, за исключением вызывающего этого событие

Answer (score 4, accepted):

когда работаем с сетями нужно помнить - мы ничего не гарантируем (особенно время доставки) всё что мы можем это сгенерировать ошибку или retry если поведение не соответсвует ожиданиям. весь вопрос не в том как передать, а что делать, если данные не пришли. я думаю лучший способ - не отправлять числа никому, пока все остальные игроки не прислали своих. т.е. ориентироваться на шаг игры а не на время. запросы от пользователя не нужны. в сокете же что хорошо - можно отправить сообщение не дожидаясь запроса. ну и на клиенте - отсылать след  число только после получения предыдущего.